# Selecting a single row of a named matrix and keeping the row name

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix with row names:

```
M <- matrix(1:15,3,5)
rownames(M) <- c("a","b","c")
colnames(M) <- c(3,2,4,6,7)
```

When selecting a single row `M[1,]`, I lose the row name information, whereas choosing a single column `M[,1]` keeps the column names. Choosing multiple rows also keeps the row names `M[2:3,]`. I guess the problem is that `M[1,]` behaves as vector. Can I do something to get a 1x5 matrix instead with row name info intact?

Comment: How would you search for something like that in R's help. Does `[]` have a functional name? BTW, nothing that someone has defined is trivial (that includes all programming languages).

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, I don't mind the downvotes. This would be helpful for some people.

Comment: OK, it seems that it is the `subset` function.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, why wouldn't you do it? I will accept it.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, Be brave :) They should downvote my question, not your answer if they are so bothered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to ZheyuanLi, we can search `?Extract` which gives the options to `[]`  (note that this is different than `?subset`). We realize that there is a `drop` argument which does the job of keeping a row matrix:  `M[1, , drop = FALSE]`.

Here is the [relevant part](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-my-matrices-lose-dimensions_003f) from R-FAQ, again courtesy of ZheyuanLi.